# Bug fix production with a migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

I am working on a Rails API, with 2 branches corresponding to my development and production environments.
I have a number of migrations ahead in my development branch, but we recently discover a bug on production that requires to add a migration on the database. However, I need to deploy this fix before merging the current state of develop, as we need extensive testing before shooting to production.

How can I handle this case ? My concern is that if I push the fix on production, the migrations on develop won't be taken in consideration after, as they are prior to the fix one.

Comment: What you would do is [rebase your current working branch](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase) on top of the hot fix. If you need to rearrange the order of the migrations you can do it by altering the file names. This might require you to first roll back the migrations on your current branch or monkey with the schema migrations table.

Comment: I believe Rails migrations run in the order of the timestamps at the beginning of the filename. Assuming the order these migrations are run matters: are you able to add a migration with a timestamp that's greater than the last timestamp in production and less than the first timestamp in the list of migrations that are in development but not in production? If you're not actually worried about order but whether the migrations might be skipped, Rails tracks which migration have been run on an individual basis and (I believe) would still run any that would look like they've been skipped.

Comment: Fortunatly, the order regarding the fix - and the migrations in development are not important (it consists in changing a column default value). I'll try to generate a migration, change its prefix prior to the last one applied and see if it's taken into account by rails.

Comment: You shouldn't have to change the file names at all then. When you run Rails DB migrate it checks the schema_migrations table to see if it has been applied. Every migration that hasn't been run is then run in the order determined by the file name. It doesn't actually matter if there are other migrations with later timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can branch out of your current production state, fix, test then merge,
- At this point, you can also merge the current state of the development branch into the production branch, which will include all the migrations that were created in development.
- If the migration timestamp of the fix is larger than the development migrations, this could cause issues in the database if the development migrations are depending on the changes introduced by the fix migration.
- To avoid such issues, you can consider changing the timestamp of the fix migration to be smaller than the timestamp of the latest migration in the development branch. This way, the fix migration will be applied before the migrations in the development branch, and any dependencies will be resolved correctly.
- You have to adjust the timestamps before running the migration